# creating a LPCTSTR pointer to a string in VS2010

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010

I have to feed a LPCTSTR in to CreateProcess.

The short question is how do I convert a std::string into a LPCTSTR?
 ( `LPCTSTR lpApplicationName = (LPCTSTR)FilePath.c_str();` does not work, CreateProcess simply ignores it, I know the path etc. I'm using is right because it works perfectly if I put in `LPCTSTR lpApplicationName = L"a//test//path//and//file";`).

The long question (why I need to do this) is: This LPCTSTR has to contain the path to, and  name of, a file I wish to run.

The process is:

1. To get the path into the right format for CreateProcess I am having
   to perform character replace (replacing single \ with double \ ) on
   the output from GetModuleFileName.  This output starts off as a
   WCHAR buffer and I then convert into a std::string.
2. I then also need to concatenate this string with the final file name
   which could be in any variable type (I define it in the program).
3. The finished string goes into the CreateProcess LPCTSTR.

I have tried using other sorts of string, but so far I haven't found any that the concatenate and character replace will work on.

Every solution I have seen does not work in Visual Studio 2010, which is what I'm using.  All advice gratefully received.

Comment: Are you doing a Unicode build? i.e. do you need to convert the  `char*` from FilePath.c_str() to a `wchar_t*`?

Comment: Unless you plan on supporting really old versions of Windows, don't bother with `TCHAR`s.

Comment: I hadn't explicitly defined a Unicode build,  but it's all Unicode (i.e it only has to work on windows XP to 8, but both 32 & 64 bit).  should i do that?

Comment: @Louise - If you are only ever building with `UNICODE` (and have no plans to support non-unicode) then you can just use `wchar_t` and `std::wstring`. The Windows API usually has three versions of all of the main functions: an ANSI one (CreateProcessA), a UNICODE one (CreateProcessW) and a TCHAR one (CreateProcess). You will just have to use the CreateProcessW one directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LPCTSTR` is a pointer to a `const TCHAR*`, not a `const char*`. Depending on your `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` settings you will need *either* a `std::wstring` or a `std::string`. If you are stuck with `std::string` then you need to convert the `char*` returned by `c_str()` to a `wchar_t*` string (or not depending on `UNICODE`).

To make life a little easier on yourself I recommend:

```
    #ifdef _UNICODE
        typedef std::wstring tstring;
    #else
        typedef std::string tstring;
    #endif
```